# Why did some of my 35mm film pictures turn out foggy/ hazy/ dull?

Tags: canon, film, 35mm, fujifilm, slr

This is my first time ever shooting with film so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Many of the photos in the roll are super crisp and clear but some have this kind of foggy haze, especially all the landscape photos I took. I attached a couple beach photos taken on the same overcast day probably 15 mins apart, also a picture of the beach on a clear very sunny day and they were all foggy. [image: This an example of the foggy photo] [image: The sea lions came out pretty clear][image][image]

The negatives of the photos are below.

[image]

[image]

Some other examples are these two photos of flowers I tried to take.

[image: The "foggy" flower picture]

[image: The flower pic negs]

Comment: This was taken on a canon ae1 program. Brand new film- Fujifilm Superia 400.

Comment: What lens?  Did you use a hood? Who developed the negatives? Who scanned them? (You or lab?) How is the density of the negatives?

Comment: As @xiota mentions - please take a picture of the negs. With film photography, your best bet to learn about a problem starts with looking at the negs.

Comment: Did you use a UV filter on the examples? There actually are legitimate reasons for putting UV filters in front of a lens when shooting color film with long vistas, especially under overcast skies.

Comment: @xiota I used the standard Canon FD 50mm f/1.8 lens with no hood. I took them to a local film shop to get them developed

Comment: I will post a photo of the negatives later today! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @David Gibson please post answers as answers rather than as comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most of the frames you show look underexposed.** But there are some that look like they might be okay. Can you explain in detail how you arrived at the camera settings you used? A properly functioning AE-1 on full auto shouldn't produce such underexposed negatives. Were you using Aperture priority with F22? Did you have it in manual mode and ignore the meter? Is the meter working? Was the film expired? Or stored poorly (in a hot car)? Etc.

**You should still be able to get *better* scans.** The lab may refuse to rescan because they're underexposed. When scanning yourself, you'll need to adjust the white/black points or brightness/contrast *in the scanner software* to maximize the amount of image data that's captured and saved. You can also try averaging multiple scans of the same frame.

---

The histogram is overly compressed:

[image: levels dialog]

After basic levels adjustment:

[image: adjusted levels]

Comment: Agreed.  The vertical lines on the first image look like some sort of digital artifacts, not something analog.

Comment: I’m in agreement with you but think underexposure may also be at play here. Would love to see the negs to confirm either way.

Comment: The image is underexposed and has then been brightened and contrast added. That will highlight any issues with the scanner itself such as these lines.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I will post a picture of the negatives later today when I get them. I'm a complete amateur with film so I'm still learning how to expose a picture properly, so highly possible I underexposed the images.

Comment: I added the pictures of the negatives @Hueco

Comment: @user85077 yep. Those negs look very, very thin. Don’t be afraid to give it some light!

Comment: For all of these pictures posted I used manual adjustments, not the AE-1 Program mode so that is most likely why all these images are underexposed. For the landscape shots I would try and have a high f stop around f/16-f/22 and change the shutter speed according to the light meter in the camera. The meter was working perfectly as far as I could tell. The film is brand new, and neither the film nor the camera have been stored in poor conditions. Would it have been better to overexpose the landscape shots or would I run into the same problem? (Ideally they would be perfectly exposed)

Comment: I'd have to look into how the AE-1 meter works. If it's a spot meter, you probably metered a bright area of the scene, which significantly underexposed the dark areas. You can try metering the bright *and* dark areas, then using an average when choosing settings. For aperture, I'd suggest F8, maybe F11. At F16, diffraction usually sets in. However, F22 does have its place. The rays of sun stars are created by diffraction.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the info! This has helped me immensely.